# VBA - how to get data from excel file just downloaded into your current excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I've got this code that downloads an excel file but how would I go about transferring the data from this file into the excel file from which I'm running the macro. You'll notice that this site provides a url to download the file directly but I'm trying to figure out how to do this without going that route because another project requires it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub GetData()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim objElement As HTMLObjectElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.housepriceindex.ca/default.aspx"
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
    .Document.getElementById("lnkTelecharger2").Click
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
    Set HTMLDoc = .Document
    Set objElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtEmailDisclaimerEN")
    objElement.Value = "Email Address"
    Set objElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("lnkAcceptDisclaimerEN")        
    objElement.Click

    ' ... Get CSV somehow ...

    .Quit
End With

Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know where the CSV is saved to?  If so, you could just open it via VBA and pull the data out, no?  Or is your question how to access the CSV online and get the data, without saving it locally?

Comment: @BruceWayne If you know how to get the data without saving it locally that would be great. If not, knowing how to access the CSV using vba would still be very useful to me.

Comment: Do you know where the CSV is being saved? If so, start the macro recorder, and just open the CSV then copy/paste the data into the Excel file. That should work, no?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any kind of CSV on that site, but I think you know where it is.  Just fund it and map the actual URL to the sample URL below.

```
Sub DownloadFileWithVBA()

Dim myURL As String
'Right-click on the link named 'Sample Address File'
'Click 'Copy Link Location'
'Paste the link below
myURL = "http://databases.about.com/library/samples/address.xls"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile ("C:\your_path\address.xls")
    oStream.Close

End Sub
```